# Free HTML Editors

Tags: javascript, html, ide, text-editor

Alright, so I've looked around the web and haven't been able to find what I'm looking for (or maybe I'm just bad at searching). So before I fire up VB.net, I thought I'd ask here. I'm looking for a free HTML editor that will close tags automatically as well as escape the tag once I'm done with it.

For example, if I were to enter:

```
<div id="blah"><p>Loreumz ipsumz
```

And then hit something (eg: Shift+Enter), it should close the paragraph tag. Hitting something again would then close the div tag, etc... Another option would be an editor that automatically closes tags as soon as you write the tag, but then when you hit something (eg: Enter or Shift+Enter), it will bring you to a new line below the closed tags. Most editors that I've seen that close tags automatically, you have to use the ctrl + arrow keys to get to the end of the line and then hit enter - very annoying and time consuming.

Bonus points for:

- HTML 5 Support
- Javascript/PHP syntax highlighting
- Auto-completion
- Cute pictures of penguins

**Edit:** This question was in **no way** open-ended or off-topic. It was a specific question regarding finding an editor that has specific features available. If there is a correct place to put this, then tell me where. Don't just insult one of your fellow members and discourage them from ever asking or helping out with questions ever again.

Comment: Although it doesn't have all the features you request, Notepad++ (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is amazing. Syntax highlighting, support for tons of languages, auto-completion... no cute pictures or auto-close tags though, but you can close tags by yourself when you use the amazing expand-contract functionality.

Comment: I actually normally use Notepad++ (Great program), I'm mainly looking for something to help improve my coding speed as small things like closing tags are a bit of a drag ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use vim with the autoclose tag plugin.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=13

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2591

Comment: I actually am really interested in Vim, and the plug-ins look like they do exactly what I want. I just get a bit... intimidated every time I go to learn it! Do you believe it is worth the learning curve?

Comment: well, my opinion would be biased - coz I LOVE vim and yes ofcourse its worth it! :)

Answer (score 1):

notepad++ is my #1 pick, aptana studio is also good if you want something that looks more "zazzy" i suppose

Comment: notepad++ with zen coding, it will change your life

Comment: You know what, I totally forgot about Zen Coding. I heard about it a long while ago and loved the idea. That may be a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, well, a step up from just 'editor' is an IDE that hits all your bonus points as well, and then some. I do all my development in [NetBeans 6.7 PHP edition](http://netbeans.org/features/php/), which also has extensive support for XML, XSLT, JavaScript, HTML, XHTML, JSON, YAML and many, many, many more. It supports proper debugging (including RESTful HTTP monitoring, and more), multiple windows, and on and on, including integration with all sorts of good tools (source-code repositories, plugins, WYSIWYG, service wizards, other wizards, templates ...)

Do I need to continue? I know the footprint is larger, but I couldn't do my job properly without it. Stand-alone editors just doesn't do it for me anymore. I'm such a IDE slut.

Comment: You had me at "IDE slut". That aside, I've looked at NetBeans before - I'm definitely interested. Last time a tried it though I noticed though it did close tags for me, I'd always have to "arrow" to the end of the line and then hit enter to start a new line. Is there a way I can create a new line after the closing tag without having to use the arrow keys/mouse?

Comment: Sure, you write your opening tag, and after you hit enter it gives you a pink version of the closing tag. Just hit enter again if you want to accept it, and you're done. Writing XML and HTML basically is as simple as writing tags and double-hitting enter.

Answer (score 0):

[Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) might work for you.